# Contrib module phpstan on Gitlab CI: How to make dependency modules available?

Tags: testing

I have a module [Decoupled Passkeys](https://www.drupal.org/project/decoupled_passkeys) that adds [JSON-RPC module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonrpc) endpoints, so it depends on JSON-RPC.

When I run tests with a custom `phpstan.neon`, I'm getting a lot of errors because phpstan cannot find the JSON-RPC module:

```
  130    Call to static method internalError() on an unknown class                                
         Drupal\jsonrpc\Object\Error.                                                             
          Learn more at https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols
```

Here's a [failed pipeline](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/decoupled_passkeys/-/jobs/1140714).

The JSON-RPC module is required in `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "drupal/decoupled_passkeys",
  "description": "Enables passkey login/registration via JSON:RPC and Webauthn.",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=8.2",
    "ext-json":  "*",
    "drupal/jsonrpc": "^2",
    "drupal/public_key_credential_source": "^1.0@alpha"
  },
```

The `phpstan.neon` looks like this:

```
parameters:
        checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false
        # Sometimes Drupal gets it wrong.
        treatPhpDocTypesAsCertain: false
        level: 9
        ignoreErrors:
          # Drupal does not define its own arrays.
          - '#no value type specified in iterable type array#'
          - '#no value type specified in iterable type Drupal\\Core\\Field\\FieldItemListInterface#'
          # Level 9 has lots of annoying offset errors.
          - '#Cannot access offset#'
```

When running phpstan from Gitlab CI via Drupal.org, how do I tell phpstan where the dependent modules are installed?  I don't want to check the dependencies for errors with phpstan, but I need phpstan to be able to access the classes in the dependencies to see what is being extended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composer file is correct; drupal/jsonrpc

The info.yml file is not correct. Only modules provided by core are prefixed with drupal, e.g. `drupal:comment`. All other modules are prefixed with the project name, e.g. `jsonrpc:jsonrpc`

Comment: Huh, despite using Drupal 8 since the launch, I somehow missed that, but the [docs clearly say so](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file).  The reason I missed it is because you can define dependencies incorrectly prefixed with `drupal/` and `drush pm-enable mymodule` still enables them as expected.